# Copying rows from one table to another excluding customer born in year 2087 and 2089

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, plsql, relational-database

I need some help here. I've a table call `ORDER_LINE`
Than have created 3 tables `ORDER_LINE_2087`, `ORDER_LINE_2089` , `ORDER_LINE_OTHER`
Have managed to copy data from `ORDER_LIN`E to both `ORDER_LINE_2087` & `2089` where the orders were submitted by customers born in the year `2087` and `2089` respectively. I would like to copy the rest of the rows that were submitted by customers not born in `2087` and `2089` into the `ORDER_LINE_OTHER` table.
Below is my query, however it copied everything from `ORDER_LINE` into `ORDER_LINE_OTHER` instead. Can anybody tell me why and let me know how can I copy the rest into the `ORDER_LINE_OTHER` table?

```
INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE_OTHER(
SELECT * FROM ORDER_LINE
WHERE OL_O_ID IN (
SELECT ORDERS.O_ID
FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMER
WHERE ORDERS.O_C_ID = CUSTOMER.C_ID
AND TO_CHAR(CUSTOMER.C_BIRTHDATE, 'YYYY') != ('2087') || ('2089')));
```

Comment: Haha...ok..I managed to figure this out already.. thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the result to a new table.

```
SELECT * INTO NEW_TABLE 
FROM ORDER_LINE 
WHERE TO_CHAR(CUSTOMER.C_BIRTHDATE, 'YYYY') !=  ('2087') || ('2089')));
```